# How to decide which statistical test is relevant for my data

Tags: python, statistics, correlation

This might not be the best platform to ask this, but I thought I would try.

I want to perform a statistical test of my data in order to validate their significance. My data is the following:

I have an online validation survey which asks participants to view a video and make a selection. Also for each annotation, they indicate their confidence in their answer.

I have analysed these results in Python using pandas dataframes and what I want is the following:
I want to see if there is a correlation between a video which has a high agreement count (i.e. a high count of participants making the same selection) and a high confidence value. So for each video, I have a selection and a confidence value for each participant. I have grouped these together to get the agreement count, shown in an example below:

```
Index Video_#   Selected Joint.1    Agreement Count
33    5         Head                24
9     2         Head                21
58    9         Hip_centre          17
128   16        Hip_centre          14
```

Here's also an example of the data before it is grouped together:

```
Index Video_#   Selected Joint.1    Confidence Value
0     33        Left_elbow          4
1     26        Left_shoulder       4
2     23        Right_foot          3
3     16        Left_hip            2
```

Is there a statistical test I can perform to find a correlation between `agreement count` and `confidence values`? Eg. Spearmnan's or Pearson's correlation? I just can't seem to wrap my head around how to use them in this context. I'm working in Python.

Thanks in advance for the help!!

Comment: you can use spearman since confidence value is ordinal (it seems). However you need to align your data across the two data frames. Is there any way to tabulate them together in the same data.frame

Comment: then you just do pd.corr(..)

Comment: @StupidWolf it would be hard to get them in the same dataframe, because the first one is grouped together by video, so it shows the agreement count for one video (so a video is shown once in all the rows), whereas in the second one, a confidence value is shown for each instance of a video, which can be multiple times. I will have to find a way to see if this is possible